# How clustering deals with autocorrelation?

Tags: econometrics

In Diff-in-Diff estimator, I did not see people using lag of outcome variable as an explanatory variable to deal with auto-correlation problem, even in some paper where the outcome variable is accounting variable, which is easily to be correlated as [Dasgupta, 2019](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/32/7/2587/5079300?redirectedFrom=fulltext)

In Diff-in-Diff, **in most case, people will cluster at the unit level** (or at the group-level depending on how you identify the heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation as mentioned by 1muflon1 [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/47772/38093))
What I am of curiousity now is **how cluster deal with auto-correlation**.

I read [this book from Scott Cunningham](https://mixtape.scunning.com/difference-in-differences.html#providing-evidence-for-parallel-trends-through-event-studies-and-parallel-leads) and saw that

> You simply adjust standard errors by clustering at the group level, as
> we discussed in the earlier chapter, or the level of treatment. **For
> state-level panels, that would mean clustering at the state level,
> which allows for arbitrary serial correlation in errors within a state
> over time**. This is the most common solution employed.

In his example, state-level is unit-level (he bases on a research of [Card and Krueger (1994)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2118030?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)). It seems that he explain that **clustering at the unit level deals with autocorrelation by allowing arbitrary serial correlation in errors within a unit over time**. However, I still not yet fully understand this approach. Is there any intuitive way to explain **how cluster deal with auto-correlation** mentioned here ?